# How do I open a Java console for an application already running?

Tags: java, windows-7, console

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I have an application running that has failed in an unusual way, and I now want to see the console. Is it possible to open the Java console once an application is already running? If so, how (on Windows 7)?

Comment: The application is normally tested in Eclipse; this was on a JNLP launch during deployment. On that particular machine, the Java console was set to ON, but not DISPLAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. 
What you can do is run your application from the **Command Prompt** and check for the errors appearing.
 The best solution is to try to run your application from **Eclipse** or **Netbeans** so you can have a better understanding of the error causing your application to fail.

**PS**: Eclipse and Netbeans are free to use.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with AlexR. I would use something like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html) to do your logging. Saves a LOT of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not have console on windows it was executed using `javaw` that does not have console by definition.

Try to use logs or JMX to debug your problem.